# java detect when any window is created or closed

Tags: java, swing, awt

Is it possible to be notified whenever any window in the application was created or closed?

At the moment I'm polling `Window.getWindows()` but I would prefer to get notified instead.

**What I have:**

```
List<Window> previousWindows = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    List<Window> currentWindows = Arrays.asList(Window.getWindows());

    for (Window window : currentWindows) {
        if (!previousWindows.contains(window)) {
            //window was created
        }
    }

    for (Window window : previousWindows) {
        if (!currentWindows.contains(window)) {
            //window was closed
        }
    }

    previousWindows = currentWindows;
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

**What I'd like:**

```
jvm.addWindowListener(this);

@Override
public void windowWasDisplayed(Window w) {
    //window was created
}

@Override
public void windowWasClosed(Window w) {
    //window was closed
}
```

Comment: Are you using AWT Window or Swing JFrame? If you're using Swing, don't tag AWT, or viceversa. Or are you using both?

Comment: It appears to be a bit of both. When I call Window.getWindows(), it's an array of awt windows. But I am using JFrames throughout the application.

Comment: For Swing and know when a window is opened: See [How do i find if a window is opened on swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890649/how-do-i-find-if-a-window-is-opened-on-swing) and [Hande JFrame Window Events](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/HandleJFramewindowevents.htm) and for AWT see [WindowListener#windowOpened](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)) from docs

Comment: Also, for better help sooner, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which you should have done atm of asking this question :)

Comment: Thanks Frak, but those solutions require me modify all the places that a JFrame is created. Is it possible to have an application-wide hook instead? Ie. Is there a way to ask the JVM to inform me whenever a window is created or closed?

Comment: I'd recommend you not to use multiple JFrames, read [The use of multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) maybe use [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or modal [JDialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) avoid the use of AWT whenever possible, it's deprecated, Swing was made to correct many problems AWT had.

Comment: Note that `JFrame`s *are* AWT `Windows`, as are the other top-level Swing containers, `JWindow` and `JDialog`.

Comment: Thanks Frak, I've updated the question to have a MCVE. We have multiple windows being created (one for each screen of a multi-screen computer).

Comment: Thanks John, yes happy to get notified of any of those too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can register listeners that receive any subset of types of AWT events via the windowing `Toolkit`.  From those you can select and handle the `WindowEvent`s for windows being opened and closed, something like this:

```
class WindowMonitor implements AWTEventListener {
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        switch (event.getID()){
            case WindowEvent.WINDOW_OPENED:
                doSomething();
                break;
            case WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSED:
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
        }
    }

    // ...
}

class MyClass {

    // alternative 1
    public void registerListener() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new WindowMonitor(),
                AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    // alternative 2
    public void registerListener(Component component) {
        component.getToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new WindowMonitor(),
                AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
    }
}
```

I would recommend alternative 2, where the `Component` from which you obtain the `Toolkit` is the main frame of your application (there should be only one), but alternative 1 should work out for you if you have to do this without reference to any particular component (for instance, before any have been created).

Do note, however, that registering an `AWTEventListener` is subject to a security check.

Comment: Superb answer! Thank you John. Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you create the additional windows (I assume `JFrame`s) yourself, you can use the `addWindowListener` method. The `WindowAdapter` abstract class allows you to override methods for the events you are interested in:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultipleWindows {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MultipleWindows().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Testing multiple windows..."));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        WindowAdapter windowAdapter = new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.out.println("Window opened: "
                                   + windowEvent.getWindow().getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.out.println("Window closed: "
                                   + windowEvent.getWindow().getName());
            }
        };

        for (int windowIndex = 2; windowIndex < 6; windowIndex++) {
            String title = "Window " + windowIndex;
            JFrame extraFrame = new JFrame(title);
            extraFrame.setName(title);
            extraFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            extraFrame.addWindowListener(windowAdapter);
            extraFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that registering a `WindowListener` on a `Window` only causes the listener to receive `WindowEvent`s fired by that `Window`, not any fired by any other `Window`s.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - yes, you are completely right. This approach is targeted at the use case where you are interested in events for the windows that you create directly. If required, you could call the `Window.getWindows` method to register window listeners for other windows as well.

Comment: @Freek de Bruijn please to see my answer here, is only for you, be sure WindowListener is correct way